# Room Persistance Library crashes with fatal isgnal 11 (SIGEGV ) on insert and delete

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have been trying to use room database in my project, but it has been crashing so far, and i cannot determine what the reason is...

Here is my case:

When a user takes a logpoint in a dialog and presses ok, then this fucntion is called

```
fun manualOkClicked() {
    /*Check if all fields are valid ( if they are, location is created and folderId is saved )*/
    if (logpoint.canCreateLocation(context) && logpoint.canSelectFolder(view?.getSelectedFolder())) {
        DataSource.saveLogpoint(logpoint)
    }
}
```

Here is how i save the logpoint:

```
fun saveLogpoint(logpoint: UserLogpoint) {
     Thread({
         mydb.logpointDao().insert(logpoint)
     }).start()
}
```

And my app crashes with this log:

```
12-27 16:17:31.108 17932-17941/com.example.myproject.debug A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x61724474 in tid 17941 (FinalizerDaemon)

                                                                  [ 12-27 16:17:31.109  2247: 2247 W/         ]
                                                                  debuggerd: handling request: pid=17932 uid=10145 gid=10145 tid=17941
12-27 16:17:31.120 2379-2379/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1514387851.111:150): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=19174 comm="debuggerd" name="com.google.android.gms" dev="dm-1" ino=65716 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0 SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0005 audit_filtered
12-27 16:17:31.131 2379-2379/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1514387851.121:151): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=19174 comm="debuggerd" name="com.google.android.gms" dev="dm-1" ino=65716 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0 SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0005 audit_filtered
12-27 16:17:31.131 2379-2379/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1514387851.121:152): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=19174 comm="debuggerd" name="com.google.android.gms" dev="dm-1" ino=65716 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0 SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0005 audit_filtered
12-27 16:17:31.209 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
12-27 16:17:31.210 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/xcover4ltexx/xcover4lte:7.0/NRD90M/G390FXXU1AQC1:user/release-keys'
12-27 16:17:31.210 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '4'
12-27 16:17:31.210 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
12-27 16:17:31.210 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG: pid: 17932, tid: 17941, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> com.example.myproject.debug <<<
12-27 16:17:31.210 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x61724474
12-27 16:17:31.210 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     r0 cb61ad58  r1 00000000  r2 3f800000  r3 00000012
12-27 16:17:31.210 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     r4 cb61ad58  r5 1335b498  r6 6fd77fc8  r7 6f96bff4
12-27 16:17:31.210 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     r8 1335b4c0  r9 de870900  sl cb61ad58  fp ffffffff
12-27 16:17:31.210 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     ip 61724474  sp e7424420  lr e9cc3c1b  pc 61724474  cpsr 200f0010
12-27 16:17:31.879 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
12-27 16:17:31.879 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 61724474  <unknown>
12-27 16:17:31.880 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00041c19  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android6Parcel14freeDataNoInitEv+32)
12-27 16:17:31.880 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00041bf1  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android6ParcelD1Ev+4)
12-27 16:17:31.880 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00097249  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
12-27 16:17:31.880 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 025b981d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ea5000) (android.os.Parcel.nativeDestroy+80)
12-27 16:17:31.880 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 025b9077  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ea5000) (android.os.Parcel.destroy+74)
12-27 16:17:31.880 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 025bc297  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1ea5000) (android.os.Parcel.finalize+42)
12-27 16:17:31.880 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 005e12b3  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-libart.oat (offset 0x47e000) (java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize+110)
12-27 16:17:31.880 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 005e14c1  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-libart.oat (offset 0x47e000) (java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run+380)
12-27 16:17:31.880 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 005f86ad  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (offset 0x56f000) (java.lang.Thread.run+48)
12-27 16:17:31.880 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 000a9241  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
12-27 16:17:31.880 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 00406e69  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+232)
12-27 16:17:31.880 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 000b0535  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+140)
12-27 16:17:31.880 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 0031636b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+58)
12-27 16:17:31.880 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 00317119  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+256)
12-27 16:17:31.880 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 0032e319  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+848)
12-27 16:17:31.880 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 00047f83  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
12-27 16:17:31.880 19174-19174/? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 0001a151  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
```

Does anybody have a clue at what's going on here and why this is crashing?

### EDIT

DataSource is an Object class which is a Singleton in Kotlin. It is initialized like so:

```
public class MyApp extends MultiDexApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

     //Initialize database
        DataSource.INSTANCE.setMyBd(
                        Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
                                MyDb.class, "my-db").build());

}}
```

Insert and delte are just annotations from room :

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(logpoint: UserLogpoint)

@Delete
fun delete(logpoint: UserLogpoint)
```

Comment: make fun delete returns Int, `fun delete(logpoint: UserLogpoint) : Int`, and check if it works

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for was in your time guys. As you may have already guessed, the problem was in something else.

The problem was in the object's classes themselves. Because room cannot parse objects that are unknown to him, he cannot parse them. Therefore i placed a converted that did just that like so:

```
@TypeConverter
fun cast2(location: String) = Utils.General.deserializeFromJson(location,Location::class.java)

@TypeConverter
fun cast1(location: Location) = Utils.General.serializeToJson(location)
```

But this doesn't work because i cannot serialize a location this way and the error i get is the one you see above.